# json format with json_encode()

Tags: php, json

I have been working with json_encode() in PHP and the output is:

```
{"Inventors:":"Wilson; Nestor Antonio Lagos (Santiago, CL)"}
{"Applicant: ":"Nestor Antonio Lagos  Santiago  N\/A  CL"}
{"Name":"Type"}
```

And I want the json format like as:

```
json = {
"Inventors:":"Wilson; Nestor Antonio Lagos (Santiago, CL)",
"Applicant: ":"Nestor Antonio Lagos  Santiago  N\/A  CL",
"Name":"Type"
};
```

I've tried but always the convertion of my array is the same.

```
$contents = "<table><tr><td>Row 1 Column 1</td><td>Row 1 Column 2</td></tr><tr><td>Row 2 Column 1</td><td>Row 2 Column 2</td></tr></table>";

$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($contents);

$items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('tr');

function tdrows($elements)
{
    $str = "";
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($elements as $element)
    {   
        if($i == 0) {
            $itm = $element->nodeValue;
            $i++;
        } else {
            if(strlen($element->nodeValue) > 1 )
            $array = array($itm => trim($element->nodeValue));
        }
        //$str .= $element->nodeValue . ", ";
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
}
```

Comment: The two examples do not show the same data structure. Why is it different?

Comment: what is the variable you are encodingf

Comment: I want the second structure, because data pertain the same id

Comment: Where are things like `Inventors` and `Applicants` in `$contents`? Where do you call `$tdrows`? I don't see how the output you're getting is at all related to the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create required json output using following snippet:

```
<?php
$people = array();
$people['Inventors']='Wilson; Nestor Antonio Lagos (Santiago, CL)';
$people['Applicant']='Nestor Antonio Lagos  Santiago  N\/A  CL';
$people['Name']='Nestor Antonio Lagos  Santiago  N\/A  CL';

echo json_encode($people);
?>
```

You are receiving output like that because you are creating a new array and inserting into $array. Use following code

```
$array[$itm] = trim($element->nodeValue);
```

and it will work.